# is it possible to get detail from web service in every 5min in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to make one system that monitor third party from NIFI.....i want to apply filter condition on invoke HTTP processor that get all the alarm from web app in every 5 min but will not fetch the duplicate alarm that already fetched before is it possible ? or else is it possible when the alarm will come in to  my web app then workflow in NIFI will trigger and do some task like update assign or delete.

THANK in advance 
[image: full data flow for your reference]

[image: detectDuplicate processor config]
[image: RedisConnectionPoolService config (this will open when i click on arrow sign in side of RedisDistributedMapCacheClientService) i have mention my web app site address with port number in connection string is it write??]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DetectDuplicate` to determine if an incoming flowfile is an exact copy of a recently-seen flowfile (as determined by a value computed from the flowfile attributes), which leverages the distributed state cache. This cache is pluggable and can be provided by a native implementation, HBase, or Redis.

Comment: Does your external web application not allow queries to specify a time window or count? If you make a request 6 times an hour, and each time it will contain the result of the last call plus a delta, you should be able to detect the difference. You could also transform the HTTP response into record format and use `PartitionRecord` to easily keep only alerts with a timestamp in the last 10 minutes. If your web app API doesn't allow request filters/parameters, there's no way to avoid fetching the data again, but you can filter it within NiFi.

Comment: thnanks @andy ...it helpful for me